# How to make my website view in mobile as small in size fit to mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already build my website which works fine in laptop or in PC , but when I type URL in mobile i am not getting the reduced size website . I have to do scrolling view all the part of the screen..
  I want my website to be in reduced size when opens in mobile or i pads, tablets etc.
  I have only 1 day remaining to submit my program .Please help me in finding the solutions.

Comment: use % width instead of fixed ones

Comment: Use Boostrap, it provides a responsive layout. http://www.getbootstrap.com

Comment: compared to what percentage i have to give. I have left side wall and right side wall add width 195px  and middle  part 996px to can i give percentage for this

Comment: User Frisidan gave the only true answer here

Answer (score 5):

Paste this in the `<head>` of your website. This will scale the website to your phone size. It also works for tablets.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: The only sensible and effective answer here, +1

Comment: @singe31 -  there will tonnes of cross browser problems will occur if you solely rely on this. Responsive Web Design will be savior over there.

Answer (score -1):

The design of web site that will adapt to different screen sizes is called as [**Responsive Design**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

There are many mechanisms are available to do this.

1. **Response JS** - http://responsejs.com/
2. **BootStrap** - http://getbootstrap.com/
3. **Phone Gap** (For Mobiles ) - http://phonegap.com

I will not encourage you to do patch work for this requirement as this will re occure. Design code in Responsive way.